# Understanding Yii2 "range" validation rule

Tags: yii2, yii2-user, yii2-validation

I am new to Yii2 Framework and I need to understand the users status. I need to create an app that assign many statuses to the user, comparing to just 2 that Yii2 gave. In Yii2 `common\models\Users` there are two constants: `STATUS_DELETED = 0;` and `STATUS_ACTIVE = 10;`. There is a block of code that limits the range of the value of status to 0-10, which is `STATUS_DELETED` and `STATUS_ACTIVE`. If I need to add other status like `STATUS_DISABLED = 20` in the `rules()` part, how do I modify this block? Do I need to remove the `STATUS_ACTIVE`and replace it with `STATUS_DISABLED`, or I should just limit the value of `STATUS_DISABLED` to be within the range of 0-10. How do I make this work? I don't understand this part.

```
class User extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
{
    const STATUS_DELETED = 0;
    const STATUS_ACTIVE = 10;
    const STATUS_DISABLED = 20; // I want to add this


    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return '{{%user}}';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            TimestampBehavior::className(),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['status', 'default', 'value' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE],
            ['status', 'in', 'range' => [self::STATUS_ACTIVE, self::STATUS_DELETED]],
        ];
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you tried to add this new status to rules: `['status', 'in', 'range' => [self::STATUS_ACTIVE, self::STATUS_DELETED, self::STATUS_DISABLED]]`? From your sample this is the only thing that could disallow this status.

Comment: @ rob006 my problem is am not sure if i'm suppose to add the new status within the rules since the rule specify a range and usually range is between two numbers. example 0 t0 10, 50 to 100 etc, so adding the new status will make it like range between 0, 10 and 20 which look so inappropriate and incorrect to me, than that's while am asking this question

Comment: This is not range in the meaning "between A and B". This actually works as "A or B or C or ..." so you may way use any number of values and value of attribute should match one of them to pass the rule.

Comment: @ rob006 now i understand, thanks so muck for your help

Comment: @rob006 add it as an answer, will help others in future

Answer (score 3):

[`$range`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-validators-rangevalidator#$range-detail) should contain array of valid values, not actual range in the meaning of "between A and B". So this:

```
['status', 'in', 'range' => [self::STATUS_ACTIVE, self::STATUS_DELETED]],
```

means that `status` should be either `0` **or** `10`. For example `5` will not be valid value. And you can add any number of values to `range` array, like this:

```
[
    'status', 'in', 
    'range' => [self::STATUS_ACTIVE, self::STATUS_DELETED, self::STATUS_DISABLED]
],
```